# How to know when client stop listening for changes in firestore for specific reference?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling to find a solution for an interesting thing I need to do in Firestore.

Would be awesome if you help me. I will try to explain:

I have something like poker tables, where users can create tables and join them. When a user has a table opened other users can see him in the table. When he leaves the table he should disappear ( here is where I have the problem )

Leaving the table can happen by navigating to other page, by closing tab, etc. He can be in the same table in different tabs, browsers or devices ( i can change this if there is no other option ).

So what I need is to display which players are connected to a table. 
Can you think of an optimal solution? How would you implement this?

.

If it helps, some things I tried but don't work:

- listen from server side when user closes the websocket that listen for changes in a table and, if there is no other socket opened for that user and table, remove that user from table.
    => it is not possible
- create a setInterval clientSide to update a timestamp in db for the user in table every 10 seconds. Then, when displaying the table, filter players by this tiemestamp being newer than Date.now() - 15 seconds
    => it doesn´t work good, it has glitches and a lot of updates to DB
- I also tried the buildPresence hack with realtime database but it doesnt help. It is just usefull for knowing that user is online, not when he leaves specific table.

Answer (score 1):

> So what I need is to display which players are connected to a table. Can you think of an optimal solution? How would you implement this?

The most simple solution I can think of is to create a collection of tables and store in each document an array of user ids:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- tables (collection)
         |
         --- tableId (document)
               |
               --- users: ["usersIdOne", "usersIdTwo", "usersIdThree"]
```

Now to check wich players are connected to a table, you can simply attach a [realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) on a document/query so you can get data in realtime. This means that once a player joins or leaves a table, the listener will fire and you'll be notified instantly.

To add a user to a table, simply add its uid in the `users` array and to remove a listener, remove its uid from the `users` array. For more informations:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Please see `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove`.

Comment: heyy i apreciate your comment, but it is solving my problem. I already solved it anyway, thankyou very much for the help